# Can i convert checkbox value to int value(0 or 1)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a checkbox in asp.net c# and I want convert the checkbox value to int. 
I have a one checkbox, label and button. I want show the checkbox value on label. I am using the code:

```
Label1.Text = CheckBox1.Checked.ToString();
```

Comment: `int value = CheckBox1.Checked ? 1 : 0` perhaps?

Comment: ... or even `(int)CheckBox1.Checked` but it's less readable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this -

```
var val = checkBox1.Checked ? 1 : 0;
```

or if you want to show in `lable` use -

```
 label1.Text = checkBox1.Checked ? "1" : "0";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ternary operator:

```
int v = CheckBox1.Checked ? 1 : 0;
```

Or even:

```
int v = (int)CheckBox1.Checked;
```